# IntelliJ IDEA CE not highlighting keys in .properties files

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, properties-file

(I'm using the Mac)
In Intellij Community Edition I'm using the default color scheme for the properties files:

- with the .properties files, the colors are not being applied to the keys, whereas the values are correctly green
- with the .yaml files, the colors are all good

I already double checked that the folders are marked as Resources Root and Test Resources Root... how should I solve this issue?

[image: application.properties]
[image: application.yaml]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the whole IDE window to better its state? If possible please share a minimal, reproducible project sample at https://uploads.jetbrains.com (please specify the UploadID here)

Comment: Hi @EgorKlepikov, thanks for your reply. I updated the original post adding the screenshots you asked for, and the demo project upload id is 2023_06_05_gnqruK1ZuyirP6QMybFtub

Comment: Looks like it happens because you're using community edition. Spring integration is available in the ultimate edition only. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grey color of a property indicates that the property is unused. You can hover the property with a mouse cursor to check it. Probably, you don't have a Spring integration if you use Community Edition and that's why IntelliJ IDEA marks these properties as unused.

In other hand YAML files in IntelliJ IDEA don't have indication of unused properties and that's why all the keys in YAML file are highlighted as used.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer! I have the same issue.
I don't think it's related to the Spring integration plugin because I tried to create all sorts of properties files in my project (those files are related to Spring) and I have the same issue everywhere.